# Slowness due course of time

Tags: ubuntu, performance, chrome

I am using Ubuntu-19.10. I was playing some offline videos in chrome. It plays smooth. I am playing this video in a loop.
I observed that,
first 4-5 round of playback is smooth
After that performance of same video's playback begins to degrade
After 4-5 of degraded performance, it plays in much worse degraded form.

During this playback, I am doing nothing other than watching video.  This video is of approx. 5 min play length. It is 1080p video.

***I wonder what/where to look for this issue.***

I tried restarting chrome, dropping cache, removing chrome's config and cache files. Hence it doesn't seems to be Chrome issue. 
Performance restored only when I reboot the system.

RAM is 4GB, GPU buffer memory is 512MB.
(I can not use anything other than Chrome.)

Comment: What happens if you wait the same length of time, then start chrome and watch the video?

Comment: Not for same length but waited for more than 10 min, then still same issue

Comment: So something (not-chrome) is changing over time. Please amend question, to make it clear what you have discovered.

Comment: Yes. I suspect about disk I/O, RAM. But don't know how to track it

Comment: Please amend question, to make it clear what you have discovered.